# Query Running slowly with subquery in it

Tags: mysql

This query is taking slowly with the subquery. I don't have access to make temp tables yet but is there anyway to further optimize this query or am I using broken logic somewhere?

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
SELECT 
       CONCAT( u.firstname , ' ' , u.lastname) as Student_name,
        u.id as Student_ID,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(u.firstaccess) as first_moodle_access,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(u.lastaccess) as last_moodle_access,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(last.timeaccess) as last_course_access,
        grp.name as Cohorts,
        cour.fullname as course 
FROM 
mdl_user as u 
Inner Join mdl_user_lastaccess as last on u.id = last.userid
Inner Join mdl_course as cour on last.courseid = cour.id
Inner Join mdl_groups as grp on cour.id = grp.courseid 
WHERE u.lastlogin = (
                     Select Max(u2.lastlogin)
                     From mdl_user as u2 
                     where u2.lastlogin = u.lastlogin
                    ) 
AND cour.id = '10189' AND 
u.firstaccess > '0' AND 
u.lastaccess > '0';
```

Comment: Try creating indexes on all fields you are using in where condition. `lastlogin`, `id`, `firstaccess`, `lastaccess`

Comment: in the subquery you should add `AND u2.id = u.id`. That may not be a huge speed boost, but the results will be more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correlated subqueries are most of the time pretty inefficient you may get better performance with an delivered table.
Most off the time a correlated subquery can be rewritten with an INNER JOIN.

I think your correlated subquery can be rewritten as follows but you need to check if the results are the same because i dont know your table structure and data.

```
SELECT 
       CONCAT( u.firstname , ' ' , u.lastname) as Student_name,
        u.id as Student_ID,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(u.firstaccess) as first_moodle_access,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(u.lastaccess) as last_moodle_access,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(last.timeaccess) as last_course_access,
        grp.name as Cohorts,
        cour.fullname as course 
FROM 
mdl_user as u 
Inner Join mdl_user_lastaccess as last on u.id = last.userid
Inner Join mdl_course as cour on last.courseid = cour.id
Inner Join mdl_groups as grp on cour.id = grp.courseid 
Inner Join(
  Select
    Max(lastlogin)
  FROM
    mdl_user
) AS u2
ON 
  u.lastlogin = u2.lastlogin
WHERE
cour.id = '10189' AND 
u.firstaccess > '0' AND 
u.lastaccess > '0';
```